# How to pass X11 events to QDialog

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt4

Currently, I am trying to pass system X11 events (on Linux) to an object I have created. To do this, I have installed an eventFilter onto my object from my QApplication. This works, in that it gets all of the events of the application. However I need to pass the object X11 events as well.

I went ahead and created a x11Event in my object, hoping that it would receive events from X11, but this does not appear to be the case.

Is there anyway to pass X11 events directly to my object, inside of my application?

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you trying to do in broader terms? For what purpose does your application need to receive X11 events?

Comment: Is your "object" the `QDialog` ? Does your reimplementation of `QApplication::x11EventFilter` return `false` to allow the reimplementation `QDialog::x11Event` function to receive the event as well ?

Comment: @alexisdm I was under the impression that x11Event could not receive the XEvent if it was not passed it by the QApplication, or parent widget? Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can receive `XEvent`s through:

- a filter function set with `QAbstractEventDispatcher::instance()->setEventFilter()` which will receive all `XEvent`s.
- a filter function set with `qApp->setEventFilter()` which will only receive events targeted at the application.
- a reimplementation of the virtual function `QApplication::x11EventFilter`
- a reimplementation of the virtual function `QWidget::x11Event` for your top level window(s) (child widgets don't receive `XEvent`s).

in that order. If any of these functions returns `true` for any event, the next function won't receive that event.

Some events can also be filtered by Qt between these functions, for example `QWidget::x11Event` doesn't receive `XKeyEvent`s (which are filtered by the `QInputContext::x11FilterEvent` function of the widget which has keyboard focus).

For more details, you should look at Qt sources: [QEventDispatcher_x11.cpp](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/gui/kernel/qeventdispatcher_x11.cpp) and the function [`QApplication::x11ProcessEvent` in QApplication_x11.cpp](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/gui/kernel/qapplication_x11.cpp#line3201)

So for the most part, if you reimplement only the `x11Event` function in your `QDialog` derived class, you should already receive most `XEvent`. And if you want your child widgets to receive them too, you could call manually their `x11Event` functions from your reimplementation of `QDialog::x11Event`.

Comment: I ended up reimplementing QApplication::x11EventFilter. Mixed up my return false and return true, though and it captured all the X11 events and broke some stuff. But got that sorted out, and seems to be working great now :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have my dev machine right now so forgive my syntax. I would do the following:

1. Declare XEvent* as a metatype:

   `int main() {
      qRegisterMetatype<XEvent*>();
   }`
2. Reimplement `QApplication::x11EventFilter` as alexisdm suggested
3. Create a signal in your QApplication reimplementation for example:

   `void dialogEvent(XEvent*);`
4. Than from anywhere in your application you can do the following:

   `QApplication *inst = QApllication::instance();`

   `MyApplication *myApp = qobject_cast<MyApplication*>(inst);`

   if(myApp != 0) {

   ```
   connect(myApp, SIGNAL(dialogEvent(XEvent*), 
            myDialog, SLOT(onXEvent(XEvent*));
   ```

   }

This way you can access x11 event globally. As an alternative you can always reimplement:

```
bool QWidget::x11Event ( XEvent * event )
```

for individual widgets

Comment: I realize that this is overkill, but nonetheless a possible solution. And besides this way you dont have to install event filters on multiple widgets.